# Adding multiple links to share on phonegap app

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

My requirement is to share three links in a single sharing using socialsharing plugin. In normal syntax provided im able to pass only single url.

example:

```
            var shareUrl='www.sample.com'
            var options = {
                subject: 'Sample subject',
                message: 'Sample message',
                url: shareUrl
            };

            var onSuccess = function(result) {
                console.debug("Share completed? " + result.completed);
                console.debug("Shared to app: " + result.app); 
            };

            var onError = function(msg) {
                console.debug("Sharing failed with message: " + msg);
            };
            window.plugins.socialsharing.shareWithOptions(options, onSuccess, onError);
```

Is there any method that i can use to share multiple urls. If its not there, will it be an issue if i share the urls in the message it self?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple URLs into the message. Just be sure to space them out so that each link can be differentiated.

Comment: But the message heading is shown as the host name of the first link in text(tested in Whatsapp)

Comment: Could you share a sample ?